# SSL Certificate on Laravel Development

Tags: laravel, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an application which i am using 'php artisan serve' command to run it on my mobile. I want to test it on my mobile but i have an API which requires HTTPS. So how can i configure this? I want to test this before I put this live.

Here is how my artisan command looks like:

```
php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.18 --port=80
```

The IP is my local machines IP Address which i am accessing from my mobile.

I have tried looking up google but i couldn't find the answer i was looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use self-signed SSL for own server.

1 - [Download](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) the certificate.

2 - Add or edit this line in `php.ini` config:

```
curl.cainfo = "[path_to_cerfificate]\cacert.pem"
```

3 - Then restart your server

Done.

Comment: I have read some where else that it is impossible to add ssl certificate to native artisan serve. It was a reply on a stack overflow question

Comment: This is the one

Comment: So it is not possible?

Comment: no, it's not possible :( use Apache or Nginx server for your local development.

Comment: What about homestead? Can I access other devices with the ip and have ssl?

Comment: yes, you can use Homestead. but i suggest you use this: http://laradock.io

Comment: Here is the thin. I have an application built on laravel. I do not want to host it on a live server. But instead i want to be hosting it on a local server. I have my own reasons not to host it on a real server xD so if i were to run this on a local “server” at my home (server as in a computer), how would I proceed